# Server sending uncontrollable amount of emails to root / postmaster

Tags: linux, postfix

Our sysops guy recently did the impossible and exported an EC2 instance onto a local Xen. While the instance was on EC2, we were sending emails through SES, but now we were forced to switch to something else -- we chose Sendgrid.

I've followed the [Sendgrid tutorial for Postfix](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html) (as a relay) and got emails sending correctly. However, since that moment, something is sending emails to something like `root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.internal` and I have no idea who or why, however my Sendgrid credits are gone in a couple of days.

I've checked my application, to see if it was sending emails to that address and it doesn't. What I'm thinking is that local services use postfix to send emails to the postmaster (things like crons running successfully and whatnot). Is my assumption correct?

And if so, how can I stop this, or how can I make it send those emails without using sendgrid? Note that we're talking about 12000 emails in a matter of days, hence my issue.

Comment: Did you bother to check the maillog to see if you're right?

Comment: @84104 what should I check there? It's just a bunch of lines showing mails being sent from either an empty string, or from the same email as the destination email, resulting in a Sendgrid error. I'm afraid there's no other info there. BTW. there are tens of entries *each second* in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned, it's possible that you have a cron running that is sending the email. If you edit your crontab (`crontab -e`) and add `MAILTO=''`, that will disable mail OR you can  pipe any output from your cronjobs to a text file or to /dev/null (e.g. `/bin/bash /some/cron > /dev/null 2>&1`).

If it's a cron job that's causing the problem, doing any of the above should help until you figure out a permanent solution.